# MySQL Database Temporarily Compromised?

Tags: mysql, security, mysql-workbench

Two days ago, I had connected to my [ClearDB](http://www.cleardb.com/) test server with MySQL workbench. I had left this workbench open and when I had checked it today, there were two new schemas named "test_justin" and "test_vishnu". I promptly reset my connection and sure enough, they were gone.

I have since reset the username and password for my database (which should have been secure enough in the first place). My questions are:

1. Has anyone encountered this as a bug in MySQL workbench or ClearDB?
2. How would an attacker create a schema when even my user account does not have permissions to do so?
3. What are some safety precautions I should be taking to ensure my database is not compromised again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries my friend! Your database was not compromised.

The systems administrator had this problem as well this week. We found out after he cursed across the room! After sending a call to our hosting provider, Heroku, it turned out that they were doing a test on a selected amount of machines (most likely on their Cedar stack) and created test schemas as a result.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm on Heroku's cedar stack as well. Thanks for your help haha

Comment: no problem, i have been meaning to make an account on this site forever - I've always been a lurker